# (HTML) Includes not Working

Tags: html, css, apache

I'm writing a script that puts a .HTML file together using a bunch of situational variables. The code comes out looking fine, and displaying fine, except for one problem - The CSS and HTML files I'm trying to include don't show up, and when I view the source, the include statements are just sitting there, however, they don't show up on the actual page.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/newsbasearchive/Images/favicon.ico" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />

      <title>NewsBase - News, analysis and business intelligence from emerging markets</title>

      <style type="text/css">
      @import url("/newsbasearchive/CSS/newsbase.css");
      </style>

      <!--#include virtual="/newsbasearchive/includes/google.html" -->


    </head>
    <body>
       <table width="1148" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <!--#include virtual="/newsbasearchive/includes/header.html" -->
        <!--#include virtual="/newsbasearchive/includes/nav.html" -->
```

The website I'm uploading this to already uses pages that include these files, and they work fine - The only difference is that those pages are .JSP (and include the pages in the .jsp way, being '<@' I think - And they all source from the /newsbasearchive/ (the root of the site), however I'm referencing the root from the path I'm giving them so I don't see why it's not working.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the whole article here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a `css` file in html using the same way you do in `jsp`. To include a style sheet in html use this format in the `head` section:

```
<LINK href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You can read more about it here: [Style Sheets in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html)